# DrawingPanel is not activate

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to learn java and I chose Eclipse to writing in Java. Unfortunately some methods are not working correct. For example "DrawingPanel" my question is what I have to do to activate this method.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't have a `DrawingPanel` class(?)
You either have to create a `DrawingPanel` class that extends a `JPanel` or import the package containing `DrawingPanel` class.

**EDIT:**
If your DrawingPanel class was under a package Panels. 
It would be  `import Panels.DrawingPanel`

If you had a package Panels/CoolDrawingPanels it would translate to  `import Panels.CoolDrawingPanels.DrawingPanel`

Comment: How can I import this class? Is there some tool in "eclipse" to import class?

Comment: What is the package (package means folder/(subfolder if any) in Java)

Comment: What I have to do to import package DrawingPanel in Eclipse?

Comment: @RPD See my updated answer, and this is assuming that you do have a DrawingPanel.java file.